# .csv file created in external storage by my android app is not visible in window explorer until I reboot the android device

Tags: android, windows, file, xamarin, storage

I have a Xamarin forms app running on a data logic scanner, it scans barcodes and writes the data to a .csv file stored in a folder in external public storage. There's no issue with reading or writing the file from the android side. The issue is when I connect the device to a PC vis USB the file is not visible unless I reboot the device. I've tried MediaScannerConnection.ScanFile, and moving the file to different folders but nothing I've tried seems to have any effect. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: where is the relevant code?

Comment: At reboot your file is indexed by the media scanner. You can invoke the scanner yourself after creating a file.

Comment: blackapps - MediaScannerConnection.ScanFile has no effect, possibly because it's not a media file or not part of scoped storage?

Comment: Would you mind sharing us a baisc, minimal project to test ? You can upload it to github and attach the link here .

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a Data Logic problem, My solution was to rename the file, do a MediaScannerConnection.ScanFile on both the new and original files paths, then rename the file back and do another MediaScannerConnection.ScanFile over both file paths.